# What's "border surfing"?

Tags: borders, terminology

In the comments of a recent answer, which had mentioned the [detention of hikers by Iran](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2009%E2%80%932011_detention_of_American_hikers_by_Iran), one of the people referred to "border surfing". What is border surfing?

**Edit:** I'd rather not have to link to the discussion in question, but it's not about water surfing: [What to use instead of credit cards in Iran?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6266/what-to-use-instead-of-credit-cards-in-iran/6268#comment7981_6268)

> getting arrested while on the other side of the border would be an
>   Iranian idiosyncrasy, wouldn't it?
>
> Not really. This could have happened during a **border surf** between
>   other countries as well.

Comment: This seems like a reasonable question to me, I've never heard of *border surfing* either. Please explain your anonymous close votes. Even if it's a throwaway term invented just for that post I think that would count as a useful if answer. Not that it would deserve many votes if it turns out that way...

Comment: One of the close votes is from me because I misinterpreted the term in the first place. But unfortunately I can't undo the close vote...

Comment: @Roflcoptr You might have to just give the definition since it looks like you coined it. :)

Comment: I've found a tiny number of usages of this term, to the point where Google has more hits from pages where "border" is the last word of a sentence and "surfing" the first word of the next.

Comment: maybe "border sweeping" is a better term?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure whether my understanding is correct or not. But here is what I was able gather from few websites and their contexts on the term 'border surfing'.

> Border surfing is a check/inspection between borders which happen randomly with no fixed times - between countries where there is no check 24/7

- An [article on edhat](http://www.edhat.com/site/tidbit.cfm?nid=86764) mentions this phrase while talking about traffic jams during inspections
- In one of the forums on [discussion](http://www.boards.ie/vbulletin/showthread.php?t=2056515566&page=2) about Scottish independence, there is a query asking whether there will be border surfing (which I presume random border checks) between Scotland and England if Scotland gets independence.