# Using Bitcoin as a cash withdrawal method in Iran

Tags: money, exchange, iran

As Iran's banking system is disconnected from the rest of the world due to sanctions there are limited ways to get Iranian Rial (IRR).
The only way I managed to find is to bring foreign currency (EUR/USD) into the country and exchange it.

For obvious reasons I prefer not carrying around large amounts of cash and I was wondering if there are places in bigger cities to exchange Bitcoins for cash(IRR), and if this is possible, what are the exchange rates?

Comment: I understand your concern, but keep in mind: Every traveller in Iran has a lot of cash on them and everyone knows this. Regardless, there is few crime especially against foreigners in Iran, so you might want to rethink your approach. And you don't need so much cash for just a few weeks of travelling. If you want to purchase something expensive (persian rugs) they usually take credit cards (via accounts in Dubai usually). I personally would trust cash more than some virtually currency which there is no guarantee anyone will exchange it for you.

Comment: Please also refer to 
this [question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6266/what-to-use-instead-of-credit-cards-in-iran/6292#6292) on what to do in Iran to not carry big amounts of cash with you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Apparently there are some non-governmental exchange shops that do this for you. Here are some examples:

*(first two links in Persian)*

https://farhadexchange.net/

**Exchange Rate:** 1.00 Bitcoin (Btc) = 9,972,300 Tomans

*Address in Iran:* Unit 1, No 13, Afshari Alley, Ostad Moein Blvd., Azadi St., Tehran

*E-mail address:* info@farhadexchange.com

---

https://exchanging.ir/buy/

**Exchange Rate**: 1.00 Btc = 10,539,000 Tomans

*Address in Iran:* Unit 6, 22 Nikouqadam Street, Tehran

*Email address:* info@exchanging.ir

---

You can also find some of the local sellers from [here](https://localbitcoins.com/instant-bitcoins/?action=buy&country_code=IR&amount=&currency=IRR&place_country=IR&online_provider=ALL_ONLINE&find-offers=Search).

Some conversions to help you better understand the units:

- 1 T ([Toman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iranian_toman)) = 10 Iranian Rial
- 1 Euro  = 4354 T

From what I understood, in order to do these operations online, you need to have a [Shetab account](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shetab_Banking_System) (which I suppose you don't). You could try contacting them to see if they have other options.

Comment: Yeah, "apparently" non-governmental.