# exchange GBP in Iran

Tags: exchange, iran

Do you know if I'll have any problems exchanging GBP in Iran?
Do they mind 50 GBP notes? I don't want to bring over only 20ies.. that'll be too much paper!

Comment: This might be helpful to you: https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/6266/1588

Comment: not at all, but always when in doubt change your money to dollar or euro. you can exchange them in Iran nearly everywhere you go. Even many shops would happily accept dollar as payment.

Answer (score 3):

GBP is amongst most popular foreign currencies in Iran and I believe you will be able to exchange it easily.

I have no experience with exchanging GBP myself, however, I had no problem in exchanging 100,200ies of Euro (in Rasht, a rather small city in the Northern Iran); 50 GBP (or even bigger notes) should be fine! *[ but anyway you should get used to carrying too much paper, as eventually in Iran you will! ]*

Comment: FYI, 50 GBP is the largest note issued by the Bank of England. Some Scottish banks have a 100 pound note, but I suspect that is harder to exchange than a Bank of England note.

Comment: and it's basically impossible to find here in London! I've never seen a 50 myself

Comment: @dau_sama Banks are all too ready to dish them out over the counter if you make a large cash withdrawal. They're actually sometimes preferred in foreign countries for exchange, contrary to the UK situation where most places won't take them!

Comment: thanks! I'll try to cash them out at the bank! it'll be easier to carry around roughly half the paper :)

Answer (score 1):

USD, EUR, and GBP are the most common currencies for exchanging in Iran, so firstly you will certainly be able to exchange your GBP note. Secondly, I recommend you to exchange your note from an authorized exchange shop rather than a bank as in Iran, exchange shops always have better rates than banks.