# How widespread is credit card acceptance in Iran?

Tags: payment-cards, iran

I have a business trip to Tabriz, Iran, and wanted to know if it was possible to pay my hotel and domestic flights by credit card or if I should also get cash to cover my hotel and flight expenses.

Do you recommend exchanging currency at the airport?

Comment: How can we know whether a hotel / airline accept credit cards? Get in contact with them and ask.

Comment: It is probably a question regarding the sanctions in Iran. So hell yeah, you can answer this question...

Comment: Please also refer to 
this [answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6266/what-to-use-instead-of-credit-cards-in-iran/6292#6292) on what to do in Iran to not carry big amounts of cash with you.

Comment: I went to the Visa website (the card company) to check for a different country. They have this excellent and very helpful advice: "If a shop shows the Visa sign outside, then they accept Visa for payment".

Answer (score 7):

I highly doubt it. International credit cards can't be used in Iran and Iranian credit cards can't also be used outside the country. So i think you better have cash to cover your hotel/flight expenses. To answer your second question, I recommend to exchange currency in the city, there are lots of currency exchange shops in the city that offer lower commissions.

Answer (score 2):

Beside the facts Gigili pointed out in their answer you can also find some websites that allow you to pay online for your hotel reservation, e.g. [pintapin](https://en.pintapin.com); but anyway, you should always carry a big load of cash with you in Iran if you don't have a local debit card!

Comment: Nope, you shouldn't carry big amounts of cash with you, there are lots of options including buying a gift card from a bank to use as a credit card while you are in Iran.

Comment: @Gigili you are right! Another useful one is what they call a [Tourist Card](http://goingiran.com/credit-card-iran-tourist-card/) that can be requested at the IKIA.

Answer (score 2):

you get a MahCard instead of carrying cash around. Mahcard is a travel debit card for tourists in Iran. for more information look at https://www.mahcard.com/ or https://www.facebook.com/themahcard/